# Incorrect 4th & 1st Quarter Sales Values in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregation

I've been writing a query to group sales by year with other columns containing quarterly sales, growth per quarter in percentage, quarter on quarter change in quarterly sales and  total annual sales in the last column from the .

I have ran the following query:

```
WITH Sales_By_Quarter AS
(
    SELECT
        DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate) AS [Year],
        DATEPART(QUARTER, OrderDate) AS [Quarter],
        SUM(TotalDue) AS [Quarterly Sales],
        SUM(TotalDue) - LAG(SUM(TotalDue)) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate) ORDER BY DATEPART(QUARTER, OrderDate)) AS [Change]
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate), DATEPART(QUARTER, OrderDate)
),
Annual_Sales AS
(
    SELECT
        [Year],
        SUM([Quarterly Sales]) AS [Total Annual Sales],
        SUM([Quarterly Sales]) - LAG(SUM([Quarterly Sales])) OVER (ORDER BY [Year]) AS [Annual Growth]
    FROM Sales_By_Quarter
    GROUP BY [Year]
)
-- SELECT * FROM Annual_Sales;

SELECT
    Sales_By_Quarter.[Year],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarter] = 1 THEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarterly Sales] END) AS [Q1],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarter] = 1 THEN (Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarterly Sales]/Annual_Sales.[Total Annual Sales]*100) END) as [Annual %],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarter] = 1 THEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarterly Sales] END) AS [4 to 1],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarter] = 2 THEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarterly Sales] END) AS [Q2],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarter] = 2 THEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarterly Sales]/Annual_Sales.[Total Annual Sales]*100 END) as [Annual %],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarter] = 2 THEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Change] END) AS [1 to 2],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarter] = 3 THEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarterly Sales] END) AS [Q3],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarter] = 3 THEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarterly Sales]/Annual_Sales.[Total Annual Sales]*100 END) as [Annual %],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarter] = 3 THEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Change] END) AS [2 to 3],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarter] = 4 THEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarterly Sales] END) AS [Q4],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarter] = 4 THEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarterly Sales]/Annual_Sales.[Total Annual Sales]*100 END) as [Annual %],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Quarter] = 4 THEN Sales_By_Quarter.[Change] END) AS [3 to 4],
    Annual_Sales.[Total Annual Sales]
FROM Sales_By_Quarter
JOIN Annual_Sales ON Sales_By_Quarter.[Year] = Annual_Sales.[Year]
GROUP BY Sales_By_Quarter.[Year], Annual_Sales.[Total Annual Sales], Annual_Sales.[Annual Growth]
ORDER BY Sales_By_Quarter.[Year];
```

I am getting right values in all columns except the 4 to 1 column. I need some help in fixing this query.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It is an expected output from an open source dataset

Comment: Read the link. It tells you want to do instead of posting images, and why not to post images.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the definition of Quarterly Change, by not Partitioning on Year, and just Ordering by it instead.

Removed the uneccesary CTE (and the join on it) for yearly figures.

Corrected the column being pivoted for `[4 to 1]`.

Ensured all columns have unique names.

```
WITH
    Sales_By_Quarter AS
(
    SELECT
        DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate) AS [Year],
        DATEPART(QUARTER, OrderDate) AS [Quarter],
        SUM(TotalDue) AS [Quarterly Sales],
        SUM(TotalDue) - LAG(SUM(TotalDue)) OVER (ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate), DATEPART(QUARTER, OrderDate)) AS [Change]
    FROM
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    GROUP BY
        DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate),
        DATEPART(QUARTER, OrderDate)
)
SELECT
    Q.[Year],

    SUM(CASE WHEN Q.[Quarter] = 1 THEN Q.[Quarterly Sales] END) AS [Q1],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Q.[Quarter] = 1 THEN Q.[Quarterly Sales] END) * 100.0 / SUM(Q.[Quarterly Sales]) AS [Q1 Annual %],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Q.[Quarter] = 1 THEN Q.[Change]          END) AS [4 to 1],

    SUM(CASE WHEN Q.[Quarter] = 2 THEN Q.[Quarterly Sales] END) AS [Q1],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Q.[Quarter] = 2 THEN Q.[Quarterly Sales] END) * 100.0 / SUM(Q.[Quarterly Sales]) AS [Q2 Annual %],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Q.[Quarter] = 2 THEN Q.[Change]          END) AS [1 to 2],

    SUM(CASE WHEN Q.[Quarter] = 3 THEN Q.[Quarterly Sales] END) AS [Q3],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Q.[Quarter] = 3 THEN Q.[Quarterly Sales] END) * 100.0 / SUM(Q.[Quarterly Sales]) AS [Q3 Annual %],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Q.[Quarter] = 3 THEN Q.[Change]          END) AS [2 to 3],

    SUM(CASE WHEN Q.[Quarter] = 4 THEN Q.[Quarterly Sales] END) AS [Q4],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Q.[Quarter] = 4 THEN Q.[Quarterly Sales] END) * 100.0 / SUM(Q.[Quarterly Sales]) AS [Q4 Annual %],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Q.[Quarter] = 4 THEN Q.[Change]          END) AS [3 to 4],

    SUM(Q.[Quarterly Sales]) AS [Total Annual Sales],
    SUM(Q.[Quarterly Sales]) - LAG(SUM(Q.[Quarterly Sales])) OVER (ORDER BY Q.[Year]) AS [Annual Growth]
   
FROM
    Sales_By_Quarter    As Q
GROUP BY
    Q.[Year]
ORDER BY
    Q.[Year]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood it. I apologize for posting the picture.

Comment: @MidhunMohan Just add the data as text, read the link for reasons why.